# Grails 3 How to access a namespace from an interceptor

Tags: grails, interceptor

I set up namespaces in my UrlMappings.groovy as:

```
"/usa_az/$controller/$action/$id?(.${format})?"(namespace: 'usa_az')
"/usa_ms/$controller/$action/$id?(.${format})?"(namespace: 'usa_ms')
```

Is there a way to do something like:

```
class NameSpaceInterceptor {

    NameSpaceInterceptor(){
        matchAll() //match all controllers
    }

    //Change the name of the view to find it in state-specific folder in views
    boolean after() { 
        if(*controller.namespace* == 'usa_az' ){
            view = "/usa_az/$view"
        } else if (*controller.namespace* == 'usa_ms' ){
            view = "/usa_ms/$view"
        }
        true
    }   
}
```

How do I find the handle to controller or more importantly the namespace in this interceptor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually did something along the lines of this:

```
boolean before() {
    if (controllerNamespace == "admin") {
    }
}
```

in one of my interceptors, so the answer should be via controllerNamespace.